# CakePHP 3.5 - router can't execute a HTML link

Tags: cakephp

I have been struggling since last few days for working my route of a HTML link. But still get no solution of the problem. I have added my project to a `virtualhost` in `Ubuntu 16.04`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/user/cakephp/employee/webroot"
ServerName cakeemployee.dev
<Directory "/home/user/cakephp/employee/webroot">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is the router code -

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Employees', 'action' => 'index']);

$routes->connect('/add', ['controller' => 'Employees', 'action' => 'add']);

$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

Here is the `HTML link` which i added to `Layout->default.ctp`

```
<div class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
            <li><?= $this->Html->link('Add Employee', '/add', ['action' => 'add']) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My  `/` route is working fine but when i try to `Add Employee` link it doesn't work and lead me to `404` page.

I don't understand is it problem with my `virtualhost` configuration or my code has problem.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the CakePHP Api you have to pass the url as string or [routing array](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-routing-array) as second parameter to the [HtmlHelper::link()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#_link) method.

In your case you can either do:

```
// Param as String
<?= $this->Html->link('Add Employee', '/add') ?>
```

or

```
// Param as Routing Array
<?= $this->Html->link('Add Employee', ['controller' => 'Employees', 'action' => 'add']) ?>
```

For debugging purpose you can always access the routes directly without link, f.e. `http://cakeemployee.dev/add` to see if the route is configured correctly (which should be the case).

Also look in the html to see, which link is generated by CakePHP. If the link is not pointing to the right location you may want to add the complete path of the url by adding `'_full'=>true` as a option to the link method. See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links for this.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to enable `mod_rewrite`.